# Porque no se seleccionan los numeros centrales

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un código el cual se llama como método neumann en el cual consiste en ingresar un numero de 10 dígitos los cuales se elevaran a la ^2 y en el resultado se tomaran 5 números centrales y el cual no se porque mi código no lo hace, si alguien me pudiera orientar se lo agradecería. 
Realizándolo en visual estudio con c#

Codigo Actualizado para solo una vez

```
double Semilla,Cantidad;
            Semilla = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            Cantidad = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            double Semilla_cuadrada = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<Cantidad; i++)
            {
                Semilla_cuadrada = Semilla * Semilla;
                String NSemilla_cuadrada;
                NSemilla_cuadrada = Convert.ToString(Semilla_cuadrada);
                if (Semilla_cuadrada % 2 == 0)
                {
                    int mitad = (Semilla_cuadrada.ToString().Length / 2);
                    string Mmitad = (Convert.ToInt32(mitad) / 2).ToString();

                    String D4,D5;
                    int suma = (Convert.ToInt32(mitad) + Convert.ToInt32(Mmitad));
                    D4 = NSemilla_cuadrada.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Mmitad), suma);
                    D5 = D4.Substring(1,5);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(NSemilla_cuadrada);
                    listBox2.Items.Add(D5);

                }
```

Comment: Tu metodo esta bien, pero debes fijarte los datos que ingresas, porque SubString(param1, param2) el parametro 1 dice de que caracter comienzas y el param2 dice cuantos caracteres tomaras de esa cadena. Si no tienes la cantidad no lo hara, no es un metodo para tomar el medio.

Comment: No me acuerdo muy bien de la sintaxis del substring en c# pero creo que los parametros (3, 5) significan que tome a partir de la posición 3, 5 carácteres a la derecha, lo cual indica que se esta asumiendo que todos los números generados tienen la misma longitud de 11, por lo cual lo primero que debe de realizar es calcular la longitud de carácteres del número, a esta cantidad restarle 5 (que son los del centro) y a la valor restante sacarle la mitad, este valor es el indice desde donde debe iniciar el substring.

Comment: @RamiroBarone que metodo me recomendarias ?

Comment: @isaac asi es pero cuando aumento de cantidad ya no funciona y no se que hacer mas porque intente como mencionas pero siempre se me cierra el programa :(

Comment: esta bien lo que usas pero si quieres sacar del medio, primero deberias ver la cantidad de carecteres que tiene tu string, luego hacer la logica matematica para deducir y ahi colocas el substring(posicionInicial, cantidad de caracteres).

Comment: debe dar un error, coloque un manejo de excepciones donde se imprima la excepción que se genera, luego actualice la pregunta con el error. puede ser que los números generados sean de longitud menor a 8 y al hacer el substring genere un error de acceso a un indice que no existe.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Pude obtener los 5 numeros de enmedio, pero ahora cuando escribo las veces que lo haga se repite lo mismo, y me enrede un poco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te hice un pequeño calculo para tomar la mitad, pero en realidad deberias decir vos desde que caracter del medio, cuantos a la izquierda y cuantos a la derecha deseas sacar, para saber cual es tu medio. Me entiendes?

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Cantidad; i++)
            {
            Semilla_cuadrada = Semilla * Semilla;
            String NSemilla_cuadrada;
            NSemilla_cuadrada = Convert.ToString(Semilla_cuadrada);
            if (Semilla_cuadrada % 2 == 0)
            {
                int mitad = (Semilla_cuadrada.ToString().Length / 2);
                string Mmitad = (Convert.ToInt32(mitad) / 2).ToString();

                String D4;
                int suma = (Convert.ToInt32(mitad) + Convert.ToInt32(Mmitad));
                D4 = NSemilla_cuadrada.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Mmitad), suma);

                Semilla = Convert.ToInt64(D4);
                Semilla = Convert.ToInt64(D4);
            }


        }
```

Comment: en este caso no sabria la cantidad de numeros, por ejemplo que metas estos numeros 1234567890 y otro 1234567892 cambia la cantidad y no sabria como calcular ello, probe el codigo que mencionaste pero me da error en lo ultimo ya intente cambiar pero no,no se si me explico

Comment: Rompe porque no estas usando los tipos de datos correctos, el numero convertido al Cuadrado supera el limite que permite el tipo primitivo.